# Is there a place where I could find Geometries of MTM Zones in Canada?

Tags: data, canada

Trying to determine automatically which zones my Lat long data is in using geometries of [MTM (Modified Transverse Mercator) Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system).

Is there any shapefile (or other format) of the different MTM zones in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Here is MTM and UTM as a KML file (in French): http://blog.cansel.ca/fichiers-utm-et-mtm-pour-google-earth/

I just took a quick look and it seems to render as dividing lines rather than polygons in Google Earth, so you may need to do some processing to close them, especially around the north and south boundaries.